# Corodva app build fails for iOS ** ARCHIVE FAILED **

Tags: ios, cordova, build, xcode10, ionic-appflow

I am trying to build my cordova app for iOS as a cloud build on Ionic AppFlow. The Android build works fine. Here is the console output:

```
Running with gitlab-runner 10.2.0~beta.147.gbd1f3fcb (bd1f3fcb)
  on ip-10-2-129-245 (dc549c99)
Creating new VM...
Running on Ionics-Mac-4.local via ip-10-2-129-245...
Cloning repository...
Cloning into 'builds/skico/sc-candidate-app-cordova'...
Checking out 16fe59ae as master...
Updating/initializing submodules...
$ fetch-updates || true
Checking for build process updates...
$ build-ios
Setting up project pipeline...
Running build process...
+--------------------------------------------+---------+----------------------------+
|                                   Used plugins                                    |
+--------------------------------------------+---------+----------------------------+
| Plugin                                     | Version | Action                     |
+--------------------------------------------+---------+----------------------------+
| fastlane-plugin-update_project_codesigning | 0.2.0   | update_project_codesigning |
+--------------------------------------------+---------+----------------------------+

[12:27:03]: Sending anonymous analytics information
[12:27:03]: Learn more at https://docs.fastlane.tools/#metrics
[12:27:03]: No personal or sensitive data is sent.
[12:27:03]: You can disable this by adding `opt_out_usage` at 
.........

+---------------------+---------------------------+
|                  Build Summary                  |
+---------------------+---------------------------+
| Job ID              | 6756030                   |
| Node.js version     | v10.16.0                  |
| Cordova CLI version | 9.0.3 (cordova-lib@9.0.2) |
| npm version         | 6.9.0                     |
| macOS version       | 10.14.5                   |
| Xcode version       | Xcode 10.2.1              |
|                     | Build version 10E1001     |
+---------------------+---------------------------+

[12:27:08]: --------------------------------
[12:27:08]: --- Step: detect_native_type ---
[12:27:08]: --------------------------------
[12:27:08]: Checking if cordova or capacitor project
[12:27:08]: Cordova project detected
[12:27:08]: -------------------------
[12:27:08]: --- Step: get_web_dir ---
[12:27:08]: -------------------------
[12:27:08]: webDir is `www`
[12:27:08]: ---------------------------------
[12:27:08]: --- Step: add_git_credentials ---
[12:27:08]: ---------------------------------
[12:27:08]: Writing git-credentials files
[12:27:08]: git-credentials successfully added to project
[12:27:08]: -------------------------------
[12:27:08]: --- Step: modify_config_xml ---
[12:27:08]: -------------------------------
[12:27:08]: No custom native config detected.
[12:27:08]: -----------------------------
[12:27:08]: --- Step: create_keychain ---
[12:27:08]: -----------------------------
[12:27:08]: $ security list-keychains -d user
[12:27:08]: ▸ "/Users/ionic/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db"
[12:27:08]: ----------------------------
[12:27:08]: --- Step: download_certs ---
[12:27:08]: ----------------------------

[12:16:54]: ▸ Compiling NSDictionary+CordovaPreferences.m
[12:16:58]: ▸ Compiling CDVWhitelist.m
[12:16:58]: ▸ Compiling NSMutableArray+QueueAdditions.m
[12:16:58]: ▸ Compiling NSDictionary+CordovaPreferences.m
[12:16:58]: ▸ Compiling CDVWhitelist.m
[12:16:58]: ▸ Compiling CDVViewController.m
[12:16:58]: ▸ Compiling CDVUserAgentUtil.m
[12:16:58]: ▸ Compiling CDVURLProtocol.m
[12:16:58]: ▸ ⚠️  /Users/ionic/builds/skico/sc-candidate-app-cordova/platforms/ios/CordovaLib/Classes/Public/CDVURLProtocol.m:60:9: 'ALAssetsLibraryAssetForURLResultBlock' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 9.0 - Use fetchAssetsWithLocalIdentifiers:options: on PHAsset to fetch assets by local identifier (or to lookup PHAssets by a previously known ALAssetPropertyAssetURL use fetchAssetsWithALAssetURLs:options:) from the Photos framework instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
[12:16:58]: ▸ ALAssetsLibraryAssetForURLResultBlock resultBlock = ^(ALAsset* asset) {
[12:16:58]: ▸         ^
[12:16:58]: ▸ ⚠️  /Users/ionic/builds/skico/sc-candidate-app-cordova/platforms/ios/CordovaLib/Classes/Public/CDVURLProtocol.m:63:69: 'defaultRepresentation' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 9.0 - Use PHImageRequestOptions with the PHImageManager from the Photos framework instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
[12:16:58]: ▸ ALAssetRepresentation* assetRepresentation = [asset defaultRepresentation];
[12:16:58]: ▸                ^
[12:16:58]: ▸ ⚠️  /Users/ionic/builds/skico/sc-candidate-app-cordova/platforms/ios/CordovaLib/Classes/Public/CDVURLProtocol.m:64:142: 'UTI' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 9.0 - Use requestImageDataForAsset:options:resultHandler: on PHImageManager for a PHAsset to request image data from the Photos framework and check the dataUTI passed to your result handler instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
[12:16:58]: ▸ NSString* MIMEType = (__bridge_transfer NSString*)UTTypeCopyPreferredTagWithClass((__bridge CFStringRef)[assetRepresentation UTI], kUTTagClassMIMEType);
[12:16:58]: ▸ ^
[12:16:58]: ▸ ⚠️  /Users/ionic/builds/skico/sc-candidate-app-cordova/platforms/ios/CordovaLib/Classes/Public/CDVURLProtocol.m:65:82: 'size' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 9.0 - Use requestImageDataForAsset:options:resultHandler: on PHImageManager to request image data for a PHAsset from the Photos framework instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
[12:16:58]: ▸ Byte* buffer = (Byte*)malloc((unsigned long)[assetRepresentation size]);
[12:16:58]: ▸ ^
[12:16:58]: ▸ ⚠️  /Users/ionic/builds/skico/sc-candidate-app-cordova/platforms/ios/CordovaLib/Classes/Public/CDVURLProtocol.m:66:133: 'size' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 9.0 - Use requestImageDataForAsset:options:resultHandler: on PHImageManager to request image data for a PHAsset from the Photos framework instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
[12:16:58]: ▸ NSUInteger bufferSize = [assetRepresentation getBytes:buffer fromOffset:0.0 length:(NSUInteger)[assetRepresentation size] error:nil];
[12:16:58]: ▸ ^
[12:16:58]: ▸ ⚠️  /Users/ionic/builds/skico/sc-candidate-app-cordova/platforms/ios/CordovaLib/Classes/Public/CDVURLProtocol.m:66:62: 'getBytes:fromOffset:length:error:' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 9.0 - Use requestImageDataForAsset:options:resultHandler: on PHImageManager to request image data for a PHAsset from the Photos framework instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
[12:16:58]: ▸ NSUInteger bufferSize = [assetRepresentation getBytes:buffer fromOffset:0.0 length:(NSUInteger)[assetRepresentation size] error:nil];
[12:16:58]: ▸ ^
[12:16:58]: ▸ ⚠️  /Users/ionic/builds/skico/sc-candidate-app-cordova/platforms/ios/CordovaLib/Classes/Public/CDVURLProtocol.m:60:63: 'ALAsset' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 9.0 - Use PHAsset from the Photos framework instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
[12:16:58]: ▸ ALAssetsLibraryAssetForURLResultBlock resultBlock = ^(ALAsset* asset) {
[12:16:58]: ▸ ^
[12:16:58]: ▸ ⚠️  /Users/ionic/builds/skico/sc-candidate-app-cordova/platforms/ios/CordovaLib/Classes/Public/CDVURLProtocol.m:63:17: 'ALAssetRepresentation' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 9.0 - Use PHImageRequestOptions with the PHImageManager from the Photos framework instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
[12:16:58]: ▸ ALAssetRepresentation* assetRepresentation = [asset defaultRepresentation];
[12:16:58]: ▸            ^
[12:16:58]: ▸ ⚠️  /Users/ionic/builds/skico/sc-candidate-app-cordova/platforms/ios/CordovaLib/Classes/Public/CDVURLProtocol.m:74:9: 'ALAssetsLibraryAccessFailureBlock' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 9.0 - Use the Photos framework instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
[12:16:58]: ▸ ALAssetsLibraryAccessFailureBlock failureBlock = ^(NSError* error) {
[12:16:58]: ▸            ^
[12:16:58]: ▸ ⚠️  /Users/ionic/builds/skico/sc-candidate-app-cordova/platforms/ios/CordovaLib/Classes/Public/CDVURLProtocol.m:79:9: 'ALAssetsLibrary' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 9.0 - Use PHPhotoLibrary from the Photos framework instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
[12:16:58]: ▸ ALAssetsLibrary* assetsLibrary = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
[12:16:58]: ▸                ^
[12:16:58]: ▸ ⚠️  /Users/ionic/builds/skico/sc-candidate-app-cordova/platforms/ios/CordovaLib/Classes/Public/CDVURLProtocol.m:79:60: 'ALAssetsLibrary' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 9.0 - Use PHPhotoLibrary from the Photos framework instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
[12:16:58]: ▸ ALAssetsLibrary* assetsLibrary = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
[12:16:58]: ▸            ^
[12:16:58]: ▸ ⚠️  /Users/ionic/builds/skico/sc-candidate-app-cordova/platforms/ios/CordovaLib/Classes/Public/CDVURLProtocol.m:80:24: 'assetForURL:resultBlock:failureBlock:' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 9.0 - Use fetchAssetsWithLocalIdentifiers:options: on PHAsset to fetch assets by local identifier (or to lookup PHAssets by a previously known ALAssetPropertyAssetURL use fetchAssetsWithALAssetURLs:options:) from the Photos framework instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
[12:16:58]: ▸ [assetsLibrary assetForURL:url resultBlock:resultBlock failureBlock:failureBlock];
[12:16:58]: ▸            ^
[12:16:58]: ▸ Compiling CDVUIWebViewNavigationDelegate.m
[12:16:58]: ▸ Compiling CDVUIWebViewEngine.m
[12:16:58]: ▸ Compiling CDVUIWebViewDelegate.m
[12:16:58]: ▸ Compiling CDVTimer.m
[12:16:58]: ▸ Compiling CDVPluginResult.m
[12:16:58]: ▸ Compiling CDVPlugin.m
[12:16:58]: ▸ Compiling CDVPlugin+Resources.m
[12:16:58]: ▸ Compiling CDVLogger.m
[12:16:58]: ▸ Compiling CDVLocalStorage.m
[12:16:58]: ▸ Compiling CDVJSON_private.m
[12:16:58]: ▸ Compiling CDVInvokedUrlCommand.m
[12:16:58]: ▸ Compiling CDVIntentAndNavigationFilter.m
[12:16:58]: ▸ Compiling CDVHandleOpenURL.m
[12:16:58]: ▸ Compiling CDVGestureHandler.m
[12:16:58]: ▸ Compiling CDVConfigParser.m
[12:16:58]: ▸ Compiling CDVCommandQueue.m
[12:16:58]: ▸ Compiling CDVCommandDelegateImpl.m
[12:16:58]: ▸ Compiling CDVAppDelegate.m
[12:16:58]: ▸ Compiling CDVViewController.m
[12:17:00]: ▸ Compiling CDVUserAgentUtil.m
[12:17:00]: ▸ Building library libCordova.a
[12:17:00]: ▸ Compiling CDVURLProtocol.m
[12:17:00]: ▸ ⚠️  /Users/ionic/builds/skico/sc-candidate-app-cordova/platforms/ios/CordovaLib/Classes/Public/CDVURLProtocol.m:60:9: 'ALAssetsLibraryAssetForURLResultBlock' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 9.0 - Use fetchAssetsWithLocalIdentifiers:options: on PHAsset to fetch assets by local identifier (or to lookup PHAssets by a previously known ALAssetPropertyAssetURL use fetchAssetsWithALAssetURLs:options:) from the Photos framework instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
[12:17:00]: ▸ ALAssetsLibraryAssetForURLResultBlock resultBlock = ^(ALAsset* asset) {
[12:17:00]: ▸ ^
[12:17:00]: ▸ ⚠️  /Users/ionic/builds/skico/sc-candidate-app-cordova/platforms/ios/CordovaLib/Classes/Public/CDVURLProtocol.m:63:69: 'defaultRepresentation' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 9.0 - Use PHImageRequestOptions with the PHImageManager from the Photos framework instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
[12:17:00]: ▸ ALAssetRepresentation* assetRepresentation = [asset defaultRepresentation];
[12:17:00]: ▸                ^
[12:17:00]: ▸ ⚠️  /Users/ionic/builds/skico/sc-candidate-app-cordova/platforms/ios/CordovaLib/Classes/Public/CDVURLProtocol.m:64:142: 'UTI' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 9.0 - Use requestImageDataForAsset:options:resultHandler: on PHImageManager for a PHAsset to request image data from the Photos framework and check the dataUTI passed to your result handler instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
[12:17:00]: ▸ NSString* MIMEType = (__bridge_transfer NSString*)UTTypeCopyPreferredTagWithClass((__bridge CFStringRef)[assetRepresentation UTI], kUTTagClassMIMEType);
[12:17:00]: ▸ ^
[12:17:00]: ▸ ⚠️  /Users/ionic/builds/skico/sc-candidate-app-cordova/platforms/ios/CordovaLib/Classes/Public/CDVURLProtocol.m:65:82: 'size' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 9.0 - Use requestImageDataForAsset:options:resultHandler: on PHImageManager to request image data for a PHAsset from the Photos framework instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
[12:17:00]: ▸ Byte* buffer = (Byte*)malloc((unsigned long)[assetRepresentation size]);
[12:17:00]: ▸ ^
[12:17:00]: ▸ ⚠️  /Users/ionic/builds/skico/sc-candidate-app-cordova/platforms/ios/CordovaLib/Classes/Public/CDVURLProtocol.m:66:133: 'size' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 9.0 - Use requestImageDataForAsset:options:resultHandler: on PHImageManager to request image data for a PHAsset from the Photos framework instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
[12:17:00]: ▸ NSUInteger bufferSize = [assetRepresentation getBytes:buffer fromOffset:0.0 length:(NSUInteger)[assetRepresentation size] error:nil];
[12:17:00]: ▸ ^
[12:17:00]: ▸ ⚠️  /Users/ionic/builds/skico/sc-candidate-app-cordova/platforms/ios/CordovaLib/Classes/Public/CDVURLProtocol.m:66:62: 'getBytes:fromOffset:length:error:' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 9.0 - Use requestImageDataForAsset:options:resultHandler: on PHImageManager to request image data for a PHAsset from the Photos framework instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
[12:17:00]: ▸ NSUInteger bufferSize = [assetRepresentation getBytes:buffer fromOffset:0.0 length:(NSUInteger)[assetRepresentation size] error:nil];
[12:17:00]: ▸ ^
[12:17:00]: ▸ ⚠️  /Users/ionic/builds/skico/sc-candidate-app-cordova/platforms/ios/CordovaLib/Classes/Public/CDVURLProtocol.m:60:63: 'ALAsset' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 9.0 - Use PHAsset from the Photos framework instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
[12:17:00]: ▸ ALAssetsLibraryAssetForURLResultBlock resultBlock = ^(ALAsset* asset) {
[12:17:00]: ▸ ^
[12:17:00]: ▸ ⚠️  /Users/ionic/builds/skico/sc-candidate-app-cordova/platforms/ios/CordovaLib/Classes/Public/CDVURLProtocol.m:63:17: 'ALAssetRepresentation' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 9.0 - Use PHImageRequestOptions with the PHImageManager from the Photos framework instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
[12:17:00]: ▸ ALAssetRepresentation* assetRepresentation = [asset defaultRepresentation];
[12:17:00]: ▸            ^
[12:17:00]: ▸ ⚠️  /Users/ionic/builds/skico/sc-candidate-app-cordova/platforms/ios/CordovaLib/Classes/Public/CDVURLProtocol.m:74:9: 'ALAssetsLibraryAccessFailureBlock' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 9.0 - Use the Photos framework instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
[12:17:00]: ▸ ALAssetsLibraryAccessFailureBlock failureBlock = ^(NSError* error) {
[12:17:00]: ▸            ^
[12:17:00]: ▸ ⚠️  /Users/ionic/builds/skico/sc-candidate-app-cordova/platforms/ios/CordovaLib/Classes/Public/CDVURLProtocol.m:79:9: 'ALAssetsLibrary' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 9.0 - Use PHPhotoLibrary from the Photos framework instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
[12:17:00]: ▸ ALAssetsLibrary* assetsLibrary = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
[12:17:00]: ▸                ^
[12:17:00]: ▸ ⚠️  /Users/ionic/builds/skico/sc-candidate-app-cordova/platforms/ios/CordovaLib/Classes/Public/CDVURLProtocol.m:79:60: 'ALAssetsLibrary' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 9.0 - Use PHPhotoLibrary from the Photos framework instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
[12:17:00]: ▸ ALAssetsLibrary* assetsLibrary = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
[12:17:00]: ▸            ^
[12:17:00]: ▸ ⚠️  /Users/ionic/builds/skico/sc-candidate-app-cordova/platforms/ios/CordovaLib/Classes/Public/CDVURLProtocol.m:80:24: 'assetForURL:resultBlock:failureBlock:' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 9.0 - Use fetchAssetsWithLocalIdentifiers:options: on PHAsset to fetch assets by local identifier (or to lookup PHAssets by a previously known ALAssetPropertyAssetURL use fetchAssetsWithALAssetURLs:options:) from the Photos framework instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
[12:17:00]: ▸ [assetsLibrary assetForURL:url resultBlock:resultBlock failureBlock:failureBlock];
[12:17:00]: ▸            ^
[12:17:00]: ▸ Compiling CDVUIWebViewNavigationDelegate.m
[12:17:00]: ▸ Compiling CDVUIWebViewEngine.m
[12:17:00]: ▸ Compiling CDVUIWebViewDelegate.m
[12:17:00]: ▸ Compiling CDVTimer.m
[12:17:00]: ▸ Compiling CDVPluginResult.m
[12:17:00]: ▸ Compiling CDVPlugin.m
[12:17:00]: ▸ Compiling CDVPlugin+Resources.m
[12:17:00]: ▸ Compiling CDVLogger.m
[12:17:00]: ▸ Compiling CDVLocalStorage.m
[12:17:01]: ▸ Compiling CDVJSON_private.m
[12:17:01]: ▸ Compiling CDVInvokedUrlCommand.m
[12:17:01]: ▸ Compiling CDVIntentAndNavigationFilter.m
[12:17:01]: ▸ Compiling CDVHandleOpenURL.m
[12:17:01]: ▸ Compiling CDVGestureHandler.m
[12:17:01]: ▸ Compiling CDVConfigParser.m
[12:17:01]: ▸ Compiling CDVCommandQueue.m
[12:17:01]: ▸ Compiling CDVCommandDelegateImpl.m
[12:17:01]: ▸ Compiling CDVAppDelegate.m
[12:17:01]: ▸ Building library libCordova.a
[12:17:02]: ▸ Running script '[CP] Check Pods Manifest.lock'
[12:17:02]: ▸ Running script 'Copy www directory'
[12:17:03]: ▸ Compiling CDVLaunchScreen.storyboard
[12:17:08]: ▸ Compiling MainViewController.xib
[12:17:09]: ▸ ** ARCHIVE FAILED **
[12:17:09]: ▸ The following build commands failed:
[12:17:09]: ▸ CompileAssetCatalog /Users/ionic/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/s-gponuhqwbnfygkcatdvqkdodeepi/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/s/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/s.app /Users/ionic/builds/skico/sc-candidate-app-cordova/platforms/ios/s/Images.xcassets
[12:17:09]: ▸ (1 failure)
```

I've checked that

- cert and build types match
- The WidgetID in config.xml is correct
- Certificate, provisioning profile, etc. are configured correctly
- The security profile in Ionic is configured correctly

I use XCode 10 as build tool.

All to no avail.

What else could be reasons for the errors?

(I was not able to post the entire output, let me know if you need other parts)

EDIT: Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --host 0.0.0.0",
    "build": "ng build",
    "webbuild": "ng build --configuration web",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "^1.0.0-beta.7",
    "@angular/animations": "^8.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "~8.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "~8.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.1.0",
    "@angular/pwa": "^0.803.20",
    "@angular/router": "~8.1.0",
    "@angular/service-worker": "~8.1.0",
    "@aspnet/signalr": "^1.1.4",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.2.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro": "^5.8.2",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.19",
    "@fortawesome/pro-light-svg-icons": "^5.9.0",
    "@fortawesome/pro-regular-svg-icons": "^5.9.0",
    "@fortawesome/pro-solid-svg-icons": "^5.9.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^5.0.0",
    "body-scroll-lock": "^2.6.4",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "cordova-android": "^8.1.0",
    "cordova-browser": "^6.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic": "^5.4.5",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^4.1.3",
    "core-js": "^3.2.1",
    "gulp": "^4.0.2",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "ng5-slider": "^1.2.4",
    "ngx-slimscroll": "^7.1.0",
    "onesignal-cordova-plugin": "^2.8.1",
    "perfect-scrollbar": "^1.4.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.3",
    "simplebar": "^4.1.0",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.801.0",
    "@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr": "~0.801.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.1.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.1.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "@types/googlemaps": "^3.30.19",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.1",
    "gulp-git": "^2.9.0",
    "gulp-run": "^1.7.1",
    "gulp-sass": "^4.0.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "ng-packagr": "^5.1.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tsickle": "^0.35.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.4.3",
    "yargs": "^13.2.4",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.4"
  },
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "onesignal-cordova-plugin": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic": {
        "APP_ID": "--app-id=\"foo\" \\",
        "CHANNEL_NAME": "Production",
        "UPDATE_METHOD": "none",
        "MAX_STORE": "2",
        "MIN_BACKGROUND_DURATION": "30",
        "UPDATE_API": "https://api.ionicjs.com"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {}
    },
    "platforms": [
      "browser",
      "android"
    ]
  }
}
```

...and the last bits of the console output:

```
Your `export_method` in gym is defined as `development`
[13:56:24]: which might cause problems when signing your application
[13:56:24]: Are you sure want to build and export for development?
[13:56:24]: Please make sure to define the correct export methods when calling
[13:56:24]: gym in your Fastfile or from the command line
[13:56:24]: 
[13:56:24]: 
[13:56:24]: Looks like fastlane ran into a build/archive error with your project
[13:56:24]: It's hard to tell what's causing the error, so we wrote some guides on how
[13:56:24]: to troubleshoot build and signing issues: https://docs.fastlane.tools/codesigning/getting-started/
[13:56:24]: Before submitting an issue on GitHub, please follow the guide above and make
[13:56:24]: sure your project is set up correctly.
[13:56:24]: fastlane uses `xcodebuild` commands to generate your binary, you can see the
[13:56:24]: the full commands printed out in yellow in the above log.
[13:56:24]: Make sure to inspect the output above, as usually you'll find more error information there
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error was fixed by removing the icon definition from `config.xml`:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.s.app" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>s</name>
    <description>
        Foo
    </description>

    <!-- THE FOLLOWING LINE CAUSED THE ERROR -->
    <!-- <icon src="resources/icon.png" /> -->

    <author email="info@s.com" href="https://www.s.com">
        sGmbH
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>
</widget>
```

I don't know why, but icons will probably need to be defined for each platform...